# UPDATE don't work in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this problem: When I submit the form the page only refresh and not Update the database.. :ss

```
<?
error_reporting(0);
require('cdn/inc/header.php'); 

if(isset($_SESSION['user_data'])):
$user_level = $_SESSION['user_data']['level'];


switch($user_level):
case 1:
case 2: 
case 3: 
case 5:
case 8:
case 9:

$query = "SELECT * FROM testes WHERE ID = :ID";
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array(':ID' => $_REQUEST['ID']) );
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 

  <input id="Title" type="text" name="Title" value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" required />


 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Salvar alterações" />
</form>

<? 
 } 
 elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $ID = $_POST['ID']; 

 $Title = $_POST['Title'];

  $queryupdate = "UPDATE testes SET Tile = :Title WHERE ID= :ID";   
 $q = $db->prepare($queryupdate);
 $q->execute(array(":Title" => $Title, ":ID" => $ID));
 header ('Location: edit.php');} 

 else {
 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM testes ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y') ASC, Title ASC);
 $stmt->execute();
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?>

 <div id="user-bar" style="background: #C16011;">
  <i>
   <a href="add.php">Adicionar</a>
  </i>
 </div>

 <br />
 <br />

 <?
 foreach($data as $index => $row) { 
 $className = $index % 2 == 0 ? "class" : "class-1" ?>

<form action="" name="Inser" method="post">
 <div class="selector">
  <input name="selector[]" class="selector" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
 </div>

   <a href="edit.php?ID=<? echo $row['ID']; ?>"><? echo $row['Title']; ?></a>


   </div>
  </h6>
 </div>

<?
 }
 if(empty($data)){?>

 <div class="no-data">
  DATA/HORA: <b><?echo date("d-m-Y");?></b>/<b><? echo date("H:i");?></b>
 <br />
  SEM NADA
 </div>

<?}
else
{?>

 <div class="btn-padding">
  <div class="btn-group dropup pull-right">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleciona uma acção</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li><a href="" class="selectall-button" onClick="return false;">Selecionar tudo / Nao selecionar</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" type="submit" class="delete-button"onclick="javascript:document.Insert.submit();">Eliminar</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>


 <?
 }
 $edittable=$_POST['selector'];
 $N = count($edittable);
 for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
 {
 $result = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM testes WHERE ID= :ID");
 $result->bindParam(':ID', $edittable[$i]);
 $result->execute();
 header ('Location: edit.php'); 
 }
 } 
?>

 <br />
 <br />

 <center>
  <small>TESTE.</small>
 </center>


</body>
</html>

<?
break;
 endswitch;
 else:
 header( 'Location: ../ ');
 endif;
?>
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this?
I dont have ideia how I can solve this, I tried everything, but the problem continue..

Comment: Is it deliberate that your DB column is "Tile" while your parameter and variable is "Title"?

Comment: What's with that switch?

Comment: Yes, why? Is not the problem ..

Comment: It's the users who can see the page @PHPglue

Comment: Where should I start? `session_start();`? `$db`?

Comment: `require('cdn/inc/header.php'); ` `session` is here..

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted, the same php file is executed again.  So you have to check for `$SESSION` and `$POST` first and action it, before you do anything else including spitting out form headers.

Comment: Can you help me how I can do this?

Comment: I can't right now, maybe I can have a stab at it later.  Unless you have a really good reason to use just one php unit, I would recommend that you split it into two forms.  It will be so much simpler for you to understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it looks like you are missing a double quote at the end of PHP string, on the line that starts:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT *
```

And for another thing, when you are debugging a problem, why in the name of sam scratch is error reporting turned off...

```
error_reporting(0);
                ^
```

You say you've tried "everything". I'd recommend you try at least turning on error reporting, and fixing the obvious problem with the string literal.

Reference: [**http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

```
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Reference [**http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

I strongly suspect that errors from PDO are also being suppressed.

Does your table **`testes`** actually have a column named **`Tile`**, or is the column name really **`Title`**?

If there's an error in the SQL statement, then PDO will catch that; and PDO will report the error if you enable error reporting from PDO.

Comment: I removed the `error_reporting(0);` and didn't show me any message .. :ss

Comment: don't appear any error, only refresh the page .. :ss